# Alternative to defining numbers

Tags: python, list

I want the user to input in 8 digits followed by a space and another single digit number. If the entered number is part of my pre made list, then the program would output the name of that item and how much of the user wants to purchase.

Here is my code

```
orange = 12345670
pineapple = 87654325
items = [orange, pineapple]
print("Input a 8 digit number followed by a space and a 1 digit number")
print("E.g. 12345670 2")
c = input("Number: ")
c1 = int(c[0])
c2 = int(c[1])
c3 = int(c[2])
c4 = int(c[3])
c5 = int(c[4])
c6 = int(c[5])
c7 = int(c[6])
c8 = int(c[7])
c9 = int(c[9])
c10 = (str(c1)+str(c2)+str(c3)+str(c4)+str(c5)+str(c6)+str(c7)+str(c8))
if str(c10) not in items:
    print("Item not found")
else:
    print("That would be "+str(c9)+" of "+str(c10))
```

The problem is that,

- It always outputs `Item not found`
- If it *does* work, it outputs `That would be *x* of number inputted` instead of `That would be *x* of orange/pineapple`.

Comment: `c10` is a string, while `items` is a list of *integers*!

Comment: You should look at dicts and the split function.

Comment: I'd encourage you to move away from dealing with individual characters and treat the entire number (both numbers, in fact) as an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use these numbers as lookups, I would store it in a `dict`, which is what that data structure is for.

```
foods = {12345670 : 'orange',
         87654325 : 'pineapple'}
```

Then you could do something like this

```
c = '12345670 2'
item, count = c.split()
item = int(item)

if item in foods:
    print('That would be {} of {}'.format(count, foods[item]))
else:
    print('Item not found')
```

Output

```
That would be 2 of orange
```

Comment: Oh great thanks! But because im kind of new to python could you explain why you did what?

Comment: Which line specifically are you unclear about?

Comment: print('That would be {} of {}'.format(count, foods[item]))

Comment: The syntax `foods[item]` is how you [lookup an item by its key from a `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) method allows you to insert values into a string without a bunch of concatenations.